# mysql backup using batch file and scheduled with windows task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have created the below batch file for backing up mysql individual tables, procedures and triggers from a database and then compress it using 7zip. when I run this in command prompt of windows it works perfectly and creates a file with name 20192004-1859.zip file size is few hundred mb But when I schedule it using the windows task scheduler it creates a file by name 20192004-.7z and the file size is just 1kb and empty too.Please find the code below and let me know how to make it work.

```
 @ECHO Off
 Echo Avoid Any MYSQL Transcations until backup completes
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%
md E:\backup\%TIMESTAMP%\Adatabase
cd D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin\
mysql -s -e "SHOW TABLES FROM Adatabase" --user=root --password=  --skip-column-names > E:\backup\tables.txt
for /f %%A in (e:\backup\tables.txt) DO (mysqldump --user=XXX --password=XXX  Adatabase %%A > E:\backup\%TIMESTAMP%\Adatabase\%%A.sql)
mysqldump --user=root --password=   --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data --routines Adatabase > E:\backup\%TIMESTAMP%\Adatabase\procNtrig.sql
E:
cd E:\backup\
C:\7zip\7za a  %TIMESTAMP%.zip e:\backup\%TIMESTAMP%\*
RMDIR /S  /q e:\backup\%TIMESTAMP%
```

Comment: Both of your lines beginning with **`cd`**, should be **`CD /D`**, because you're also **changing drives**! You can also remove the line which reads just **`E:`**.

Comment: Thanks that did solve the issue, but still did not understand the reason behind it. As the batch file was running directly from command prompt and not from the task scheduler. Is it important that when we change drives in an batch file we should use /D

Comment: `CD` changes directory, to change drives, you need to use the `/D` option. This information can be noted when reading the output of `CD /?` at the Command Prompt.